# How can I download NuGet after build as part of a .csproj file so that I can create a .nupkg file?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, nuget, nuget-package

I have a C# project that has some .dll I would like to package up in to a .nupkg file. This works fine when nuget.exe is downloaded already to the .nuget folder, but when nuget.exe is not present it will not download automatically, even though the .nuget\NuGet.targets file has a setting `DownloadNuGetExe` which has been set to `true`.

After some investigation, it seems that nuget.exe will not download if there are no packages to import. But I require nuget.exe to be downloaded so that it can create a .nupkg file on developer machines and on a build server (and not to manage importing packages/references in to the project).

How can I work around this limitation? I would prefer a solution that modifies only the .csproj file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We managed to find a solution, by importing the .nuget\NuGet.targets file and then calling the target named _DownloadNuGet like this:

```
<CallTarget Targets="_DownloadNuGet" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the best solution, but we generally put the nuget.exe into the .nuget folder, and ensure that this gets checked into source control so that it just gets downloaded when the developers pull down the latest code.

It's not the most elegant solution, but since we actually nuget-ized our code & thus we no longer have a monster solution that contains everything, we discovered that every solution/project needs to provision its own nuget.exe somehow. This approach has been working for us, hope it works for you too...!